# Filtrar dados de controlleres diferentes em Angular

Tags: angularjs

Estou com uma dificuldade em filtrar os sistemas de clientes dentro do *select*.

Vou explicar:

Tenho cliente *A* que tem o sistema *1* e *2*, tenho o cliente *B* que tem o sistema *3*.

Ao selecionar o cliente dentro do *select*, eu quero que o *select* do sistema puxe somente o sistema que o cliente tem contratado, se selecionar o *B* quero que apareça apenas o sistema *3* para selecionar.

```
 <label for="sel1">Selecione um cliente</label>
    <select ng-required="true" class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="solicitacao.id_solicitacao_cliente" ng-controller="clienteController">  
      <option disabled></option>
      <option value="{{cliente.id_cliente}}" ng-repeat="cliente in cliDados | orderBy:'nomecli'">{{cliente.nomecli}}</option>
    </select>
    <label></label>
    <label for="sel1">Selecione um sistema</label>
    <select ng-required="true" class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="solicitacao.id_solicitacao_sistema" ng-controller="sistemaController">
      <option disabled></option>
      <option value="{{sistema.id_sistemas}}" ng-repeat="sistema in sisDados | orderBy:'nomesis'">{{sistema.nomesis }}</option>
    </select>
```

Em outras palavras, não faço ideia como passar o *ID* do primeiro *select* após selecionado.

Comment: Uma pergunta: Por que controllers diferentes se eles estão 'relacionados' um com o outro?

Comment: Para cada tabela do banco eu fiz um controller diferente, cliente tem um controller só pra ele, sistema tem um outro controller só pra ele, ou seja, ele utiliza cada controller para buscar no banco a informação e preencher o select com o ng-repeat, pois não uso essas informações apenas nessa tela. Eles não estão relacionados um com o outro propriamente dito, são controllers independentes. A ligação entre eles ocorre por meio de um terceiro controller (controllerContrato), onde eu informo que cliente X tem o sistema Y.